# How to clip an incomplete coastline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip

I have the park boundary for Point Reyes National Seashore (https://irma.nps.gov/DataStore/Reference/Profile/2224545?lnv=True) and the NHD data for that park boundary. I want to do a drainage density analysis, but I don't want to include the 400m of water that extends beyond the shoreline in my area, not to mention the bay. I want to clip the park boundary to the extent of the shoreline, but the shoreline is an incomplete polygon (the park is connected to land!) so I can't actually clip it.

What is the best method to clip this to the seashore in a relatively quick manner?

Comment: Can you include an image of the layers your working with so we have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What formats are your datasets in? If the park boundary is a polygon then you can use the split editing tool. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-a-polygon.htm. Just trace the coastline and use the trace to do the split.